# The breakpoints not match the code line when debug in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: debugging, sql-server-2008-r2, breakpoints

The breakpoints not match the code line when debug in SQL Server 2008 R2. Sometimes when hit the breakpoints,but not executing the right code line.How to fix it?

```
declare @SharedTable table(Num int,Name nvarchar(50))
Insert into @SharedTable(Num,Name) values('27149','Vader')

declare @numShared int=0;
select @numShared = COUNT(Num) from @SharedTable
declare @idx_Shared int =1

while @idx_Shared<=@numShared
begin
    declare @Num int;declare @Name nvarchar(50)
    select @Name=Name,@Num=Num from @SharedTable
    declare @AllSharers nvarchar(max)=''
    set @AllSharers+=('Num:'+Cast(@Num as nvarchar)+'    '+'Name:'+@Name+CHAR(10))
    set @idx_Shared+=1
end

print @AllSharers;
```

Very simple code copy from my query.
Every time the debug pointer step to line `select @Name=Name,@Num=Num from @SharedTable`,it'll ignore the code below in the 'while' loop, and from then on all the code below and breakpoints begin to mismatch.

Copy it to a new query,the problems still are there,but typed the content the same in a new query,the problem gone.

Comment: Can you be more specific or provide an example?

Comment: Codes is a little long , i also can't find where the problem is, the codes run normally.May the text format can cause the problem?

Comment: And sometimes the pointer of breakpoints may jump back to the line above the breakpoint currently hitting.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will report the line of code a given statement started on when reporting an error or hitting a breakpoint.  Thus, if you have something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [tableName]
WHERE 1 = 'text'
```

If you place the breakpoint on line 3, SQL Server is going to break at line 1 (and report that the error occurred on line 1 when you continue), because the statement did, in fact, start on line 1, and whitespace is irrelevant in SQL.

Comment: The code doesn't have any error,it runs normally,only the breakpoints not match the code line.

Comment: The same can be said for breakpoints. If you put a breakpoint on line 3 of what I wrote, it'll break on line 1.

Comment: There's nothing like this in my code, May be I'm not say clearly. When the breakpoint is hitting, the next step to execute is not the code where the breakpoint stands but another.

Comment: The question really can't be answered without example code, then.  Please provide an example and I or someone else will do our best to help you out I'm sure.

Comment: May be I can may shorter code to represent the problem,I am trying